# C# Неправильные данные в сокете

Tags: c#, сокет

Если вызывать код без паузы несколько раз то в сокет попадают данные с прошлого вызова.

```
_text="...";//Некие текстовые данные
byte[] data = new byte[_text.Length];
data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_text);
_socket.Send(data)
```

Как этого избежать не тормозя поток через

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Comment: `data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);` — это вообще компилируется? Покажите ваш настоящий код.

Comment: Вот. Поправил...

Comment: А `byte[] data` у вас локальная переменная, или поле? Дайте воспроизводящий проблему пример. [mcve]

Comment: Локальная переменная. Пример не могу дать. Там много различного софта используется. Мне просто непонятно почему при однократном вызове все в порядке а при многократном - проблемы.

Comment: Проблема где-то ещё, не в том. коде, который вы показали. Может, вы вызываете это одновременно из разных потоков?

Comment: В одном потоке, но несколько раз очень быстро. Например 5 раз в секунду вызывает функция с этим кодом. При этом данные в _text попадают из другого источника что само по себе занимает несколько секунд. Может в этом дело.

Comment: А зачем вы массив байт выделяете? Причём странного размера

Comment: Залогируйте ваш текст перед отправкой, увидете, что реально уходит. Или вы неправильно из сокета вычитываете.

Comment: Размер массива байт ни на то не влияет. Пробовал от 1 до размера _text. Логировал, естественно. Все нормально. Информация в _text та, что нужна. Забыл указать: размер _text может быть до 50 мегабайт.

Comment: @jshapen естественно не влияет, т.к. вы этот массив не используете, да длина текста и количество байтов не одно и тоже

Comment: Что значит не использую?

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, то что сокеты это непредсказумая штука, неизвестный может быть пинг между клиентов и сервером.

Я бы посоветовал Вам, отправить сначала размер, потом данные или признак окончания строки (Маркеры).

Лучше используйте UDP, т.к TCP это поток, в которые данные набегают, а потом лишь отправляются. Могу ещё посоветовать написать свой протокол поверх TCP, но это большая мука...